# How to use Fetch API to retrieve and send data from form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, fetch-api

I have html form:

```
<form action="file.php" method="post">
    <input name="formName" type="text" />
    <input name="formEmail" type="email" />
    <input name="formSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit Me!" />
</form>
```

So how to use Fetch API in order to get those values and send them to file.php file using ajax?

Comment: Take a look at this page here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-the-javascript-fetch-api-to-get-data

Comment: @FotisGrigorakis thanks, but I need an exact example with form and php.

Comment: you can follow the steps from the site i wrote and do it your way. ;)

Comment: @FotisGrigorakis In your link there's no example of sending data from a form using fetch

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? How is this problem related to PHP itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

```js
function submitForm(e, form){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    fetch('file.php', {
      method: 'post',
      body: JSON.stringify({name: form.formName.value, email: form.formEmail.value})
    }).then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    }).then(function(data) {
      //Success code goes here
      alert('form submited')
    }).catch(function(err) {
      //Failure
      alert('Error')
    });
}
```

```html
<form action="file.php" method="post" onsubmit="submitForm(event, this)">
    <input name="formName" type="text" />
    <input name="formEmail" type="email" />
    <input name="formSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit Me!" />
</form>
```

Comment: It says "Error".

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The path was not correct.

Comment: Improvement: Use addEventListener to run the submitForm> `document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', submitForm)`

Comment: using `const submitForm = (e) => {  e.preventDefault();  const form = e.target;     fetch('file.php', { .... `

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use `FormData`.
It uses the same format a form would use if the encoding type were set to "multipart/form-data". [More details about it.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

```
    const submitForm = () => {
        const formEl = document.getElementById('formId');
        const payload = new FormData(formEl);

        fetch('file.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: payload,
        })
        .then(Result => Result.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            // your code comes here
        })
        .catch(errorMsg => {
            console.log(errorMsg);
        });

    };
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const formSubmit = {
  const sendData = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({
      'name': 'name',
      'email': 'ab@gmail.com'
    })
  }
  fetch('url',sendData)
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(data => console.log('Data',data)
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How does your approach provide any new insights that were not already part of the other answers?