# Using HTML, CSS and JavaScript Fetch to make a POST request to an API service

Tags: javascript, dom, fetch-api, login-page

I have an assignment about using JavaScript API. I don't know anything about JavaScript APIs. Can anyone help me? I wrote the login page with html CSS code. But the second stage of the assignment:

- When the login button on the login page is clicked, the values ​​entered in the username and password inputs will be received with JavaScript and a request will be sent to the service here https://fakestoreapi.com/docs#a-login. When a response comes from this service, a redirection will be made to the dashboard page from the login page.

I'm very new to the software, I searched for a video to learn, but I couldn't find it for the login page. Can anyone help me.

I was able to create a login page using only html CSS.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Change this to get the values from your HTML: `username: "mor_2314", password: "83r5^_"` and use addEventListener on the form submit event to do so

Comment: @mplungjan  I don't know how to add this to my login page (which I wrote using html css)

Comment: I just told you. Lookup [submit event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event) and [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: For example this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45370120/how-to-use-fetch-api-to-retrieve-and-send-data-from-form - but using the addEventListener instead of inline event handling - see my comments to the answer in the link

Comment: I will review it now. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check out this before anything else:

- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

You said in your question that you code this using html and css, so there should be a `<form>` attribute and because you don't send a back-end server, so I guess this will do:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {


      loginform.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        const username = document.getElementById("username").value;
        const password = document.getElementById("password").value;
        const data = {
          username,
          password
        }
        fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/auth/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
          })
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(json => console.log(json))
          .catch(err => console.log(err.message));
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="loginform">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" id="username" name="username" value="mor_2314">
    <input type="text" placeholder="password" id="password" name="password" value="83r5^_">
    <input type="submit" value="login">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

The code provided here https://fakestoreapi.com/docs#a-login do not have `header type` method, remember to add it in. Once received the data you should change how the code should react in each of their corresponding section.

In the success case, it returns JSON format:
[image]

The failed case returns an error (and seemingly an HTML page), so I use `.catch` to catch it:
[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: I strongly suggest you use the submit event of the form. If not, then the form tags are not even needed

Comment: No you did not. Please do NOT use the click event of the submit button but instead use the submit event of the form plus event.preventDefault() like [the  other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78210868/295783) did. Also w3schools is not a great resource. MDN is good

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events

Comment: @mplungjan thank you. for the part that like the answer like the other answer, I was writing my answer during and after the selected post, but if my answer is too bad, I will happily delete it.

Comment: Not a problem. It is just a pet peeve of mine when ppl use inline event handlers or button clicks on a form... The DOMContentLoaded is a great idea

Comment: I pasted the codes you sent into my file named index.html. Then I ran it and yes, when the correct password and username is entered, it displays as shown in image first,({token: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOjIsI…M5OH0.1PXy98iAn6rKUlh9D9qQU_6Fx65JNel3LLL1G2We3O8'} but when I enter it wrong, 
index.html:17 
        
        
       POST https://fakestoreapi.com/auth/login 401 (Unauthorized)
(anonymous) @ index.html:17
index.html:26 Unexpected token 'u', "username o"... is not valid JSON

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would implement it

```js
myform.addEventListener("submit", function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    let fields = this.querySelectorAll("[name]");
    let obj = {};
    for (let field of fields) {
        obj[field.name] = field.value;
    }
    fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/auth/login',{
            method:'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body:JSON.stringify(obj)
        })
            .then(res=>res.json())
            .then(json=>console.log(json))
});
```

```html
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username" value="mor_2314">
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" value="83r5^_">
    <input type="submit" value="login">
</form>
```

I created a form and a submit event for it. I preventDefault in the submit event so we don't do a postback. We also specify that our values are JSON and convert our collected values into JSON.

Comment: How can I add this to my index.html page or should I create a new javascript file? and thanks a lot @lajos-arpad

Comment: @Elal you can simply wrap a `<script>` tag around the Javascript part, like `<script>...</script>`. If this answer works, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: @Lajos: [How do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)